# Should I use getXXX() or the (private) variable inside the same class?

Tags: java, getter-setter

In `java` when I'm writing a class is it recommended to use the `getXXX()` method or use the variable name using `'this'` keyword to refer to the `private` variables in the same class  `public` methods?

Comment: There's good reason to, there's good reasons not to.  If the getter can be overridden, then I would suggest you should use the `getter` especially if the value it returns is important to the overall state of the object

Comment: Key is to declare variable private. Once this is done , getXXX or this.variable is matter of style. By default, go with getXXX style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is - it depends.

Yes, I would also recommend that you start by making your variables `private`, there are cases where this may not be required, but lets stay on subject and only ever allowing access to them via getters

Now assuming your have a `public` getter for your instance field, this raises the potentially that some one else will want to override this method and change it in some way, maybe return a calculated value based on new values they have introduced or what ever.

If the `private` field is part of any internal calculation or changes the state of the object logic in some way, then you start having problems, as you are now ignoring the value that is returned by the getter, which would produce undesirable results.

In this case, you must consider the value returned by the getter over the `private` field.

Comment: Using the field instead of the getter makes it harder to change the representation of the object's state. For example you might want to do `point.x`, `point.y` to `point.r`, `point.theta`. But if you used the fields, you have to go back and replace `point.x` with `point.getX()`. If you had just been using `point.getX` all along, you wouldn't have to make such a change.

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs That assumes you started with `public` field instances and are retro fitting, I'm talking about new development...

Comment: My above comment would apply to a situation where he is starting with `private` instances writing a method `public double getL1Norm(){ return Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y);}` for the first time. I was stating that `public double getL1Norm(){ return Math.abs(getX()) + Math.abs(getY());}` wouldn't need to be modified if he changed the internal representation of the `point`.

Answer (score 2):

this.pvtMemberVariable (or) pvtMemberVariable to be used in the same class. Getters are public methods used by the outside classes

Comment: What happens if the state of the class is dependent on the values returned from the getters and the instance variables simply make up the current implementation?

Comment: if the getter simply returns the pvtMemberVariable, I feel there is no difference between using getter() or directly accessing the pvtMemberVariable. If you are doing something extra, for example, getter(){ if(pvtMV==null) pvtMV=new Object(); return pvtMV;}. then it makes sense to use getter()

Comment: What happens if I extend your class and override the getter to return something else? Your (original) class is no longer using it and would start giving incorrect results - I'd have to know where this value is being used internally, know how it relates to the workings of your class and re-implement those methods as well...and yes, I've had to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Reason for keeping variables private is to hide them from unrequired modification from other classes. However while accessing private variables in its own class, developer is aware of its state. It is feasible to use private members from its own class directly. This will reduce method calls and serve the purpose of privacy.

Answer (score 0):

I think it really depends on your situation. For me, one situation that I often use the getter method is if the variable might not be initialized yet, for example if I am using lazy-initialization. But for most situations, I just reference the variable directly.